# SharedPreferences/Context Throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to pass some values from an activity to a non-activity receiver class in order to create a notification. I can't see why I'm getting an error on this one. I mean, I passed the context, retrieved it, and used it accordingly. I read some threads about this issue and did my best to solve it, but this is how far I could come. I'm getting an eror on this line:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
```

**DailyForecastActivity.java**

```
public class DailyForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Daily[] mDays;
    public static Context contextOfApplication;
    @Bind(android.R.id.list)
    ListView mListView;
    @Bind(android.R.id.empty)
    TextView mEmptyTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();

        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        TextView mLocationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MainActivity.DAILY_FORECAST);
        mDays = Arrays.copyOf(parcelables, parcelables.length, Daily[].class);
        DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter(this, mDays);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyTextView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String dayOfTheWeek = mDays[position].getDayOfTheWeek();
                String condition = mDays[position].getSummary();
                String tempMin = mDays[position].getTempMin() + "";
                String tempMax = mDays[position].getTempMax() + "";
                int icon = mDays[position].getIconId();

                String message = String.format("%s Summary: %s", dayOfTheWeek, condition);
                Toast.makeText(DailyForecastActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("summary", condition);
                editor.putString("tempMin", tempMin);
                editor.putString("tempMax", tempMax);
                editor.putString("dayOfTheWeek", dayOfTheWeek);
                editor.putInt("icon", icon);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

        String area = gpsTracker.getSubLocality(this);
        String city = gpsTracker.getAdminArea(this);
        String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
        mLocationLabel.setText(area + ", " + city + ", " + country);
    }
    public static Context getContextOfApplication(){
    return contextOfApplication;
    }
}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context applicationContext = DailyForecastActivity.getContextOfApplication();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
    String summary = preferences.getString("summary", null);
    String tempMin = preferences.getString("tempMin", null);
    String tempMax = preferences.getString("tempMax", null);
    String dayOfTheWeek = preferences.getString("dayOfTheWeek", null);
    int icon = preferences.getInt("icon", 0);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.applicationContext = context;
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(dayOfTheWeek + " Weather")
            .setContentText(summary + "Temperature: " + tempMax + "/" + tempMin)
            .setTicker("Daily Weather");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.theoc.stormy.Receiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2565)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
                                                                at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
                                                                at com.theoc.stormy.Receiver.<init>(Receiver.java:42)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2560)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

**EDIT**

I solved the NPE error, but now I'm getting "null" for my SharedPreferences values. I ran a debug in DailyForecastActivity, where I'm putting the values, and there seems to be no problem there. I'm able to put all the values I want. Looks like I'm unable to retrieve the SharedPreferences in Receive.java. Also as a side note, I'm getting the notification sound for some reason, but not getting any notification at all.

Comment: what is there at line 42 in `Receiver.java`

Comment: I think your context is null

Comment: debug line by line and check on which line code is breaking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RRR I already wrote the line that's giving the error.

Comment: With all due respect, no other question should be asked here containing Null Pointer Exception if that's the case. I know how to solve NPE's, yet I don't see why it's giving null in this one. To me, my context shouldn't be null. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

initialize `SharedPreference` in `onReceive`

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

It might be possible when your `BroadcastReceiver` is called your activity is null

Comment: this solved the error, yet now I'm getting "null" for all my SharedPreference values. Do you have any clue on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

First, instatiate your application in the manifest by linking to a class

```
<application
    android:name = ".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Then implement the following method whitin your application class

```
public class App extends Application {
private static final String TAG = ".App";
private static Context context = null;

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static Context getContext() {
    if (context != null) {
        return context;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "App was not successfully created");
        throw new Error("App was not successfully created");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I always get my shared preferences by using:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can also verify whether the preference file is created or not in your application data/ directory.
Please, read carefully how shared preferences works in android.

Answer (score 0):

By calling in `DailyForecastActivity.java`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

and in `Receiver.java`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
```

You are calling for **two different instances** of `SharedPreferences`. You are saving in one, then you are trying to get from second, where you didn't save anything, so you are getting `null` for all values. You must unite it and use the same in first and second situation, like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in `DailyForecastActivity` and

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in `Receiver`, which will result in getting the same instance.

Also you can try using the same `Context`. `Context` get from `getActivity()` is not the same `Context` get from `getApplicationContext()`. So use `getApplicationContext()` in both situations or pass `Context` via parameter in constructor from activity.